# how to run a montecarlo analysis in Brightway

Tags: montecarlo, brightway

I am trying to run a simple montecarlo analysis with brightway, but I am having some trouble to understand the procedure. The [getting started notebook](https://brightwaylca.org/examples/getting-started.html) had an example, but I think is outdated (the iterate method I think has been changed). There are some notes on the [seminar](https://github.com/PoutineAndRosti/Brightway-Seminar-2017/blob/master/Day%202%20PM/Performance.ipynb) about how to optimise time but it is not very clear what a conventional way of running a montecarlo analysis for a single activity (or a comparative one).

I kind of understood the MultiMonteCarlo method e.g,

```
act_dict_list=[{bw.Database('ei_34con').random():1},
               {bw.Database('ei_34con').random():1},
               {bw.Database('ei_34con').random():1},
               {bw.Database('ei_34con').random():1},
               {bw.Database('ei_34con').random():1}]

mmc=bw.MultiMonteCarlo(act_dict_list,method=ipcc2013,iterations=10)
mmc.calculate()
```

but for some reason all results are equal for the same activity and simpler methods are probably more appropriate for a simple calculation.

[EDIT]: this was due to a bug that is now solved, the MultiMonteCarlo now works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple analysis can be done quite quickly (response based on [this](https://github.com/PoutineAndRosti/Brightway-Seminar-2017/blob/master/Day%201%20PM/Brightway%20and%20uncertainty.ipynb)):

```
random_activity=bw.Database('ei_34cutoff').random()
random_method=bw.methods.random()
MC_random_activity=bw.MonteCarloLCA({random_activity:1},random_method)
%time MC_random_act_scores = [next(MC_random_activity) for _ in range(100)]
```

A multiple montecarlo can be done using the approach of the answer, that right now does not have any bug

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is a bug, please file an issue.

Comment: Fixed in 1.6.4.

Comment: Cool, If I want to use dependent sampling to compare two activities, would it just suffice to use the same seed with the MonteCarloLCA method ?

Comment: In theory, yes, but it would be easier to just re-use the technosphere and biosphere matrices with `redo_lcia()` and the other functional unit on *each iteration*.